# SQL statement for GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am really stucked with one sql select statement.

This is output/result which I get from sql statement below:

[image]

WHAT I need: I need to have columns assignedVouchersNumber and usedVouchersNumber together in one row by msisdn. So for example if you can see "msisdn" 723709656 there are two rows now.. one with assignedVouchersNumber = 1 and second with assignedVouchersNumber  = 1 too.

But I need to have it in one row with assignedVouchersNumber = 2. Do you now where is the problem?

```
SELECT eu.msisdn,
   eu.id as userId,

   sum(case ev.voucherstate when '1' then 1 else 0 end) as assignedVouchersNumber,
   sum(case ev.voucherstate when '2' then 1 else 0 end) as usedVouchersNumber,

   ev.extra_offer_id,
   ev.create_time,
   ev.use_time,
   ev.id as voucherId,
   ev.voucherstate
FROM   extra_users eu
   JOIN (SELECT sn.msisdn AS telcislo,
                stn.numberid
         FROM   stats_number sn
                JOIN stats_target_number AS stn
                  ON ( sn.numberid = stn.numberid )
         WHERE  stn.targetid = 1) xy
     ON eu.msisdn = xy.telcislo
   JOIN extra_vouchers AS ev
     ON ( eu.id = ev.extra_user_id )
WHERE  ev.create_time BETWEEN '2012-07-23 00:00:00' AND '2013-08-23 23:59:59'
   AND ev.use_time <= '2013-08-23 23:59:59'
   AND ev.use_time >= '2012-07-23 00:00:00'
   AND ev.voucherstate IN ( 1, 2 )
   AND Ifnull(ev.extra_offer_id IN( 2335, 3195, 30538 ), 1)
   GROUP BY eu.msisdn, ev.extra_offer_id, ev.voucherState
ORDER  BY eu.msisdn ASC
```

Comment: Your problem is in ev.extra_offer_id, it is different between the two lines.

Comment: @Eugene How do you mean this? I updated my sql statement above but the problem is still there.

Comment: @JohnnyGreenwood See Mani's comment on his answer. If you select just the first four columns, you should see no duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different extra_offer_id for same msisdn and VouchersNumber. Thats why you get two rows.

Comment: I have updated my sql statement to form as you say but the problem is still there...

Comment: You have used it in group by, selecting it wont be a problem with repect to Mysql. Remove it from group by

Comment: It is working, now I have grouped and counted assignedVouchersNumber and usedVouchersNumber... but still if there is msisdn with value 723709656, there are two rows... one with assignedVouchersNumber = 2 and usedVouchersNumber = 2 ... is it possible to have it all in one row by msisdn?

Comment: If you want it in a single row, remove voucherstate from group by and do max() or min() on date and other columns to fetch data as you desire.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!!! After removal of voucherstate from group by it is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

I got it... there should not be groupping by ev.voucherState in

```
GROUP BY eu.msisdn, ev.extra_offer_id, ev.voucherState
```

After then I have removed ev.voucherState it is working now.